# Extracting Blocks of Information from txt file and create a Pandas dataframe and store

Tags: regex, python-3.x

I have a big txt file which includes chat transcripts, My goal would be extract different components and create a Pandas Df to store in it. A sample of the chat is as below:

> ```
> *****************************************************
> Session:123456
> Chat Date: 2017-05-01T08:01:45+00:00
> Chat exec name: Sam
> Member name: Sara
> 2017-05-01T08:01:45+00:00 Sara: I need help on element A
> 2017-05-01T08:01:47+00:00 Sam: Sure I can help you on this one
> 2017-05-01T08:01:48+00:00 Sara: Is there a better product
> 2017-05-01T08:01:48+10:00 Sam: Sure we have a lot of new products
> 2017-05-01T08:01:49+18:00 Sara: Can you let me know
> 2017-05-01T08:01:51+20:00 Sam: Here is the solution
> 2017-05-01T08:01:52+00:00 Sara: Thanks for this
> 2017-05-01T08:01:52+11:00 Sam: Have a Nive day Bye!!
> *****************************************************
> Session:234567
> Chat Date: 2017-05-02T18:00:30+00:00
> Chat exec name: PAUL
> Member name:CHRIS
> 2017-05-02T18:00:30+00:00 CHRIS: I need help on element A
> 2017-05-02T18:02:30+00:00 PAUL: Sure I can help you on this one
> 2017-05-02T18:02:39+00:00 CHRIS: Is there a better product
> 2017-05-02T18:04:01+00:00 PAUL: Sure we have a lot of new products
> 2017-05-02T18:04:30+00:00 CHRIS: Can you let me know
> 2017-05-02T18:08:11+00:00 PAUL: Here is the solution
> 2017-05-02T18:08:59+00:00 CHRIS: Thanks for this
> 2017-05-02T18:09:11+00:00 PAUL: Have a Nice day Bye!!
> *****************************************************
> ```

If I am able to create a table with the columns:

Session, ChatDate, ChatExecName, Membername, Time, Person, Sentence

The first 4 columns should be repeated for the complete block of chat. besides the delimiters are fixed and they never change.

I have tried this but this returns all blocks together can somebody please help.

```
import re
def GetTheSentences(infile):
    Delim1 = '*****************************************************'
    Delim2 = '*****************************************************'
  with open(infile) as fp:
    for result in re.findall('Delim1(.*?)Delim2', fp.read(), re.S):
        print (result)
```

and

```
import re
def GetTheSentences2(file):
    start_rx =re.compile('*****************************************************')
    end_rx = re.compile('*****************************************************')
    start = False
    output = []
    with open(file, encoding="latin-1") as datafile:
        for line in datafile.readlines():
            if re.match(start_rx, line):
                start = True
            elif re.match(end_rx, line):
                start = False
            if start:
                output.append(line)
        print (output)
```

Comment: This looks like a job for a parser not regex alone.

Comment: Can you guide me through a sample code/solution

Comment: Not really. My knowledge about this subject is outdated. I used to use Bison. Just google 'parser' and choose an approach that works for you.

Answer (score 0):

I sure hope this is helpful:

```
data = '''*****************************************************
Session:123456
Chat Date: 2017-05-01T08:01:45+00:00
Chat exec name: Sam
Member name: Sara
2017-05-01T08:01:45+00:00 Sara: I need help on element A
2017-05-01T08:01:47+00:00 Sam: Sure I can help you on this one
2017-05-01T08:01:48+00:00 Sara: Is there a better product
2017-05-01T08:01:48+10:00 Sam: Sure we have a lot of new products
2017-05-01T08:01:49+18:00 Sara: Can you let me know
2017-05-01T08:01:51+20:00 Sam: Here is the solution
2017-05-01T08:01:52+00:00 Sara: Thanks for this
2017-05-01T08:01:52+11:00 Sam: Have a Nive day Bye!!
*****************************************************
Session:234567
Chat Date: 2017-05-02T18:00:30+00:00
Chat exec name: PAUL
Member name:CHRIS
2017-05-02T18:00:30+00:00 CHRIS: I need help on element A
2017-05-02T18:02:30+00:00 PAUL: Sure I can help you on this one
2017-05-02T18:02:39+00:00 CHRIS: Is there a better product
2017-05-02T18:04:01+00:00 PAUL: Sure we have a lot of new products
2017-05-02T18:04:30+00:00 CHRIS: Can you let me know
2017-05-02T18:08:11+00:00 PAUL: Here is the solution
2017-05-02T18:08:59+00:00 CHRIS: Thanks for this
2017-05-02T18:09:11+00:00 PAUL: Have a Nice day Bye!!
*****************************************************'''

data = data.split('*****************************************************')
data = [item.split('\n') for item in data if item]
result = []
for group in data:
    group = [item for item in group if item]
    times = []
    people = []
    lines = []
    for item in group:
        if item.startswith('Session'):
            session = item.split(':')[-1]
            print session
        elif item.startswith('Chat Date'):
            chatDate = item.split(':', 1)[-1]
        elif item.startswith('Chat exec'):
            execName = item.split(':')[-1]
        elif item.startswith('Member'):
            memberName = item.split(':')[-1]
        else:
            times.append(item[:25])
            people.append(item[26:].split(':')[0])
            lines.append(item[26:].split(':')[-1])
    for i in range(len(times)):
        result.append([session, chatDate, execName, memberName, times[i], people[i], lines[i]])

import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(result, columns=['Session', 'ChatDate', 'ChatExecName', 'Membername', 'Time', 'Person', 'Sentence'])

print df
```

Comment: Thanks very much @zipa, this helps for now. Really nice!!! Appreciate it!!!